# ¿Quiero saber como servir páginas web html desde la base de mi cpanel?

Tags: html, css, base-de-datos, web

Hola mi nombre es Javier y mi pregunta es: 
Tengo un página web con más de 20 subpáginas servidas desde el html_public de mi servidor, ¿está es la única manera de gestionarlas o sea desde html_public o se puede servir estas mismas páginas desde la base de datos que hay en mi cpanel(MySQL-Php). Gracias.
**Aclaración:** Pregunto esto porque voy a tener más subpáginas talvez unas 100, es de un proyecto personal y aún estoy aprendiendo php y javascript. Y me preocupa si no hay problema gestionar todas las páginas html solo desde el html_public.

Comment: el cpanel es de acceso privado.. podrias explicar mejor la situacion o porque queres hacer esto? ademas ninguno de los tags que pusiste es relativo a este problema... mira [ask] y hace el [tour] si no lo hiciste

Comment: si tu duda se refiere a que con "Cpanel" es el unico administrador de archivos para tu web, pues la respuesta es no, tienes muchas alternativas y entre ellas puedes ocupar Filezilla para gestionar tus archivos del servidor, y si tu duda no tiene nada que ver con eso intenta formular y a expresar tu duda. Saludos

Comment: ¿Tu pregunta es "*¿Quiero saber como servir páginas web html desde la base de mi cpanel?*"?, no lo se... preguntatelo a ti mismo ¿lo quieres saber?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Que es el html_public? es el espacio que los hosting tienen para la publicación de archivos. Es decir... todo lo que allí figure será visto por quien acceda al dominio (a excepción claro que hagas algún cambio en el htaccess del servidor).
Entonces para publicar un html, un php o cualquier otro objeto debe estar en esa carpeta o en subcarpetas de la misma.

Tu consulta es si se pueden gestionar las paginas html desde un cpanel. La respuesta corta es que no se puede. Porque? En realidad el cpanel tiene múltiples funciones, muchas de las cuales son administrativas del hosting. En cuanto a los html, el cpanel tiene un administrador de archivos que te permite cargar o mover los html y otros objetos. Pero en realidad la gestión del contenido de las páginas o el proceso de "servirlas" (es decir decidir que pagina mostrar en función de lo que el usuario esté buscando), no puede resolverse desde el cpanel.

Para ello debes construir un modelo basado en PHP + HTML que interprete lo que el usuario está queriendo hacer y presente la página o el objeto que deba servirse para dicha acción.

Un ejemplo: supongamos una página principal que tiene una guía de como resolver trámites. Cada trámite tendrá un texto y un botón de acción asociado (con +info). 
Cuando el usuario ingresa a la página principal (index.php) habrá una pagina que le sirva el contenido de la misma y los botones de acción. Cuando el usuario presione uno de los botones, estará llamando a otra página (una sub-página) que le abra un formulario con campos para llenar.
Entonces el concepto de "servir" es en realidad presentar cada página en el momento que el usuario la necesita. Eso se resuelve con una programación PHP que al momento de carga toma los parametrios que el usuario envió y toma definiciones que parte mostrar y que no.

En mi caso he construido un php principal con dicha estructura con un gran [switch](http://php.net/manual/es/control-structures.switch.php) que dependiendo del parámetro GET o POST que el usuario envíe (a través de los formularios y acciones que realice) decide que contenido servir al usuario.

Ojala esta informacion sea de tu utilidad.

Comment: Muchas gracias Claudio su respuesta fue de mucha utilidad. +1